Chisel Wordpress Installation - Error: Failed to get current SQL modes
I've run into an issue trying to setup a WordPress using Chisel. I'm using VS Code, XAMPP on Windows.
After successful download of WP Chisel tries to setup connection with database and here I'm encountering the problem: Reason: '"mysql --no-defaults --no-auto-rehash --batch --skip-column-names --execute="SELECT' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. I've checked my PATH and directory for mysql properly set, and mysql commands work fine.
Success: WordPress downloaded.
? Enter the database host: 127.0.0.1
? Enter the database port: 3306
? Enter the database name: digsite
? Enter the database user: root
? Enter the database password: [hidden]

Error: Failed to get current SQL modes. Reason: '"mysql --no-defaults --no-auto-rehash --batch --skip-column-names --execute="SELECT' is not recognized as an internal or external command,   
operable program or batch file.


Trying again...

I'm quite new into development so if I forgot about some crucial specification please let me know! Thank you!
